# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. MVC Role Authorization

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, profile

This appears to have solved the issue. In modules in web config, I added this line...

I am attempting to limit access to a controller class by role:

```
namespace tvc.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public class productsController : Controller
    {
```

User management is working in my application. I'm able to create users, assign roles, log in, etc. However, when I add (Roles="Admin") to the [Authorize] attribute, I get the SQL Server error. I'm guessing that MVC is looking for the local database (in app data), but I don't know where I'd change that behavior and this is production and a remote DB is used.

I would like to know why I'm getting this error and how to properly use the role attribute.

Comment: Check your web.config for connection string and update that to the correct one (db server/user credentials etc)

Comment: yes - defaultconnection is set to remote db and used succesfully for user administration

Comment: might also be `<appSettings>
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
</appSettings>` or the mvc5 `<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="RoleManager" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>`